# REGEX How to remove multiple ocurrences of unknown Names from a text? Using Positive lookahead and Backreferences

Tags: regex

I have this exemple of my regex:

```
((\S(?!\.|por |, | se | que ).)*(Inc|LLC).((?!\.|por |, | se | que ).)*|\d?\D*\d{4}\D?\d{4})(?=.*?\1)
```

The intended result was for it to get **ALL** the "NAMES" that are on the text, considering only that they are appearing multiple times in the text.

And I don't know what the names are going to be, only that they will appear multiple times in the text as if in headers, footers or titles.

My limitations are that it needs to be written in regex and nothing more, consider the configurations on the demo.

I've tried and created a demo for easy visualization

## [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kkrhg8/5)

I want to match **ALL** of the occurrences,

Leaving one or two unmatched at the end doesn't help, in the demo for exemple the last line is all unmatched, and it shouldn't (the placement is to help visualize what is left unmatched, but it could be anywhere on the text)

- Also, please consider that there are some "names" (i've underlined them in yellow) that really aren't supposed to be matched, because, or they don't have multiple ocurrences, or they are blocked by a negative lookahead.

[image]

Comment: How do you define names? It's a pretty flexible concept that I don't think can be written as a simple pattern.

Comment: For the current exemple they are defined by the Inc. and LLC tags as company names, but that could be changed.

The Idea or definition of "names" is something that I want to leave open, it could be considered as a string of random (like names), that is very hard to distinguish from the rest of the text.

The important idea is that they would appear over and over in the text, for exemple a header in a document where configurations and formatting were lost by turning it into simple text.

The regex above is very good for that purpose(finding/marking), but it misses the last occurence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?:(\b(?!com)[A-Za-z]+)\s*(?=Inc|LLC)(?=.*?(\1)))|(\d{4}-\d{4})(?=.*?(\3))`

https://regex101.com/r/exUXDc/1

**Explanation**

If you want to find duplicate data, you need to find at least two occurrences of this data. Then we can satisfy this requirement by finding whether the data appears in front or behind.

So we need to use Positive Lookahead `(?=...)` expression to check if the selected data appears later, and if it does, we need to match the data. Here is the simplest example: https://regex101.com/r/exUXDc/2, `(.)(?=.*?\1)` to find if a character appears later.

Of course, you also need to determine whether the data has appeared before it, and if it has, you need to match the data. This time I thought of a sure Positive Lookbehind `(?<=...)`  expression. This is also a simple example (find the character `a` but require that the character `a` also appears before it.) :`(?<=a.*?)(a)` https://regex101.com/r/exUXDc/3 , it works perfectly. When I replace it with `\1` it doesn't work. Example:`(?<=\1.*?)(a)`https://regex101.com/r/exUXDc/4 This one stumped me, I analyzed it and found that because regular expressions are parsed from left to right, it doesn't work properly when `\1` is written on the left. Then I modified for this expression `(.)(?=.*?(\1))`https://regex101.com/r/exUXDc/5 , which satisfies the requirement, but I think it is a little flawed.

Then replace the `.`  is replaced by the character that needs to be matched to form this complex expression: `(?:(\b(?!com)[A-Za-z]+)\s*(?=Inc|LLC)(?=.*?(\1)))|(\d{4}-\d{4})(?=.*?(\3))`

This regular expression is composed of two sub-expressions

The first one:`(?:(\b(?!com)[A-Za-z]+)\s*(?=Inc|LLC)(?=.*?(\1)))`

The second one:`(\d{4}-\d{4})(?=.*?(\3))`

If you understand what I've said above, writing the following regular expression is not a problem at all.

Of course, it would be great if you could solve my flaws above~

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong with the OP's code and how you fixed it.

Comment: I've noticed that you split the groups and added a non capturing group at the start of the regex, can you somehow explain how does that helped make it work on the last occurrence?

It does make it work.

Comment: I understood it better, Thanks!

there were some edits I didn't really like, which you'll be able to see on the revised demo:
https://regex101.com/r/kkrhg8/7

For example, the key indicative that it is a name could be in the middle of the string.

But making \1 into a Capturing Group by setting it like (\1)
made everything work, it was quite a minor edit, but i'm very thankful for all the trouble.

I'll leave the revised Improved regex here:
`((?<=\s)((?!por |,|\.com).)+(Inc\.|Inc| & |LLC)((?!por |,).)*(?=\s)|(?<=\s)\d?\D*\d{4}\D?\d{4}(?=\s))(?=.*?(\1))`