# Regex that matches all non consecutive repeating patterns

Tags: javascript, regex

I Have a long string of none sense that it's each character is either a number [0-9] or a lowercase letter [a-z] like the following

> "0z8b816ne139z1b948bjk50f9498t139gjj90t7tb3509w6h0r7tbp"

what I'm looking for is a regex that matches all non consecutive patterns that occurred more than once in the string
I want the output to be like the following example

bold parts are the matched ones

> "0z**8b**816ne**139**z1b94**8b**jk50f9498t**139**gjj90t**7tb**3509w6h0r**7tb**p"

Comment: What do you mean by "non-consecutive"? If the string were `"1a1a"` should `"1a"` and `"1a"` be matched, even though they are consecutive? They would be matched in the selected answer. In your example you have not matched any single-character strings, such as `"1"`. If a pattern must contain at least X characters (from your example, presumably X=2) you should say so. Suppose the string were `"1a2x1a2ya2"`. should both `"1a2"` and `"a2"` be matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regex:`(..+)(?=.*?(\1))`

[image]

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75805868/regex-how-to-remove-multiple-ocurrences-of-unknown-names-from-a-text-using-posi/75808274#75808274)

```js
const regex = /(..+)(?=.*?(\1))/gm;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('(..+)(?=.*?(\\1))', 'gm')

const str = `0z8b816ne139z1b948bjk50f9498t139gjj90t7tb3509w6h0r7tbp
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Nowadays, it's much more convenient to use `.matchAll()`: `for (const match of string.matchAll(regex)) { console.log({ ...[...match] }); }`.